# Add Controller to index.html in an Angular SPA

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

My Angular app has several views. The `index.html` file which has the `<div ng-view></div>` also has a header/navbar that has links to each of these views.

The `$routeProvider` is configured to load respective views and their controllers.

Considering this setup, where each of the views has its own controller, how do I add CSS `class="active"` to the appropriate link in the header when navigating within the app?

**Extra Info.:**
I added `ng-click="set_page_id(x)"` and `ng-class={active: active_page_id === x}` to the links and realized there's no controller associated with the `index.html`. I wrote a jQuery function to make this work by listening to click events but it doesn't work when a view itself calls another view. I wonder if there's a better, Angular way.

Comment: The $rootScope object is recognized on the whole application, including the index.html page. Have you tried using that?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that'll provide me a means to share data betwixt controllers. That can be done using a global variable as well. How do I conditionally do something on the index.html page is my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your main or nav controller with something like:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $location) {

  $scope.menu = [
    {label:'Home', route:'/'},
    {label:'About', route:'/about'},
    {label:'Contact', route:'/contact'}
   ]

  $scope.menuActive = '/';

  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(e, curr, prev) {
   $scope.menuActive = $location.path();
});

});
```

Then

```
<li ng-repeat="item in menu" ng-class="{active: item.route == menuActive }"><a href="#{{item.route}}" >{{item.label}}</a> </li>
```

Heres a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g0tCe0McJM9BriJNK7XE?p=preview)